# How to replace showModalDialog()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

One of my requirement is to launch a pop-up and , to do some work after the pop-up is being closed by the user.(for eg, to refresh the parent window..).
So, I decided to use the modal dialog to launch a pop-up , something like below, as the statement below the showModalDialog() function will not be executed as long as the pop-up itself is not closed.

```
//pop-up the new dialog
window.showModalDialog()
// do some work on parent window here
```

Now, the problem is that, some of major browsers like Chrome don't support modaldialog anymore, and I need to change my code  to make it work.
I think, window.Open() is the only option(since I can't use jquery dialog plug-ins for some reasons) , but the problem of window.Open() is that , there's no way to detect when the pop-up window is closed by the user.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How about a polyfill - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400388/showmodaldialog-alternative

Comment: @Aidan, Thanks. Does it work on iOS mobile browsers ?

Comment: The code that cannot execute until modal popup is suppressed is JavaScript or .NET code?