# JavaScript window.showModalDialog() not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

**`window.showModalDialog()`** not working from ASP.Net page on Chrome Version *51.0.2704.84m*. 
What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [window.showmodaldialog not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500345/window-showmodaldialog-not-working-in-chrome) but did not help much. But came to know that we need to use window.open for Chrome as window.showModalDialog is deprecated in Chrome
Then found some useful info http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodal.htm it worked.

```js
function modalWin() {
  if (window.showModalDialog) {
    window.showModalDialog("xpopupex.htm","name",
      "dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
  } else {
    window.open('xpopupex.htm','name',
      'height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes'
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what does continued from previous do ?

Answer (score 1):

`window.showModalDialog` is deprecated from the web standards. You can use a polyfill like https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog and continue using it normally.

```
    function() {

    //statements before showing a modal dialog

    var returnValue = window.showModalDialog( url [, arguments, options] );

    //statements after closing a modal dialog

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`showModalDialog` is deprecated in IE since IE 4

Reference Link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

---