# MVC Open an HTM page from Javascript action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, showmodaldialog

I am doing a MVC App. IT is a migration from ASP.NET.

in my _`Layout` I have a `Footer` that shows a message with a link to show Terms and Conditions.  That Link opens a `Htm` with all legal advices.

My intention is that Link calls a JavaScript action that open the Htm page. Like this.

```html
 function ShowTerms() {
            document.bgColor = "#E9EAED";
            oReturn = window.showModalDialog('TermsAndConditions.htm', window, 'dialogHeight:680px;dialogWidth=620px;resizable:no;status:no; help:no');
            document.bgColor = "";
        }
```

My JavaScript call is like this.

```html
<span class="Term" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="javascript:ShowTerms();">Terms y Conditions</span>
```

I have several erros when I display it. IIS do not find the page, and things like this.

Is that posible? or I have to call a Controller, Action Method and open it with Boostrap ShowModal?

Thanks

Comment: You can give your link an id and then refer that id in your Javascript and write a function for it.

Comment: You mean to call a HTML.ActionLink?. I added how I call me JavaScript function.. thanks

Comment: I assume this is asp.net-mvc? (you need to tag you question correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span class="Term" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">Terms y Conditions</span>

var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("Term")[0];

ele.addEventListener("click",function() {
        document.bgColor = "#E9EAED";
        oReturn = window.showModalDialog('TermsAndConditions.htm', window, 'dialogHeight:680px;dialogWidth=620px;resizable:no;status:no; help:no');
        document.bgColor = "";
    });
```

I don't know what browser you are using but Window.showModalDialog() is deprecated in modern browsers. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog). Another option you can use which you can also read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25122874/5138921)

Answer (score 0):

Another working example.

```
<dialog>
<p>
    <q id="linkId"></q>
</p>
</dialog>

<span class="Term" id="show" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">Terms y Conditions</span>



document.getElementById('show').onclick = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
document.bgColor = "#E9EAED";
var link = document.getElementById('linkId');
link.innerHTML = window.open('http://www.mozilla.org','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;};
```

You could try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w70zw9bw/).